# django-mongodb engine saves data in which collection?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I am using django-mongodb engine to connect django with mongodb. I have a model in my application named as bandwidth. when i save data through python manage.py shell , it saves data in a collection named as app_bandwidth. How does this engine saves this data?? Also can I modify the collection name to be per_app_bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the collection by setting the `db_table` in the `MongoOptions` meta class.

See: http://www.django-mongodb.org/reference/model-options.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding class Meta to your model Class:

```
from django.db import models

class AnyDoc(models.Model):
    # some attributes
    name =   models.CharField(max_length=64)
    class Meta:
        db_table='your_collection_name'

    #
```

This is working with:
 [Django](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.7.x) <=1.7
django-mongodb-engine 0.6.0
djangotoolbox 1.8.0

There are some examples of earlier versions around using the notation:

```
class MongoMeta:
    db_table='your_collection_name'
```